# Плитка изображений разных размеров

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, scaffolding

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как адаптивно сверстать подобный блок.

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вопрос в названии

Comment: @Qwertiy Если использовать флекс, то ячейки сетки будут одинаковой высоты. Если использовать сетку бутстрапа, то картинки не будут прижиматься к в верхним

Comment: @Qwertiy пробовала columng-count, в некоторых случаях картинки съезжают в конец + сортировки правильной не добиться. Пробовала masonry, тоже не получается. Покажите как можно если можете

Comment: @Vesneta, flex, vertical, wrap.

Comment: Гуглите [masonry layout](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/mdExgmZ)

Comment: @nazarpunk пробовала, работает не так как на картинке

Comment: Ну так сделайте [разметку](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-image-gallery-with-css-grid-e0f0fd666a5c/) сами.

Comment: @nazarpunk Спасибо, но сайт динамический. Суть в том чтобы картинки были в оригинальных непредсказуемых пропорциях

Comment: @Vesneta для динамических сайтов есть [media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) , да и никто не мешает просто сверстать три столбика и заполнить их изображениями.

Comment: можно использовать грид